# Yii2 dependent DropdownList State and City

Tags: yii2

I followed a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepxKw8VA7w) tutorial to create a dependent DropdownList (State and City), and soon after loading, the Dropdownlist City displays all cities.

I wish none were displayed, just when selecting a State. But I'm not sure how to do it and would like some help.

Look how I did:

VIEW: `_search.php`

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'state_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(State::find()->all(), 'id', 'nome'),
                [
                    'prompt'=>'Selecione',
                    'onchange'=>'
                    $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/city/lists').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                        .done(function( data ) {
                            $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'city_id').'" ).html( data );
                        }
                    );'    
                ]); 
?>

<?= $form->field($model,'city_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(City::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
                [
                    'prompt'=>'Selecione o estado',
                ]); 
?>
```

CONTROLLER: `CityController.php`

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countCity = City::find()
            ->where(['state_id' => $id])
            ->count();

    $cities = City::find()
            ->where(['state_id' => $id])
            ->all();

    if($countCity > 0 )
    {
        foreach($cities as $city ){
            echo "<option value='".$city->id."'>".$city->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option> - </option>";
    }

}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population_2010` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `state` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sigla` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in onchange()

```
  $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/city/lists').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                    .done(function( data ) {
                        $( "select#selectid" ).html( data );
                    }
                );' 




                <select id="selectid"></select>
```

and you have to return option value from

```
actionList($id){
                               $list=Model::findBySql('your quer where id=$id')->all()
             foreach($list as $l){ echo "<option  value='" $l->id."'>'.$l->name.'</option>';
               }
```

I recommend you to watch this video

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bpj7dF2orbI

Comment: Hi, on search page works fine, but on profile page don't save.